# iPhone Forever Plan, Theft of Phone

Tags: iphone

This isn't exactly a technical hardware question, but policy and strategy regarding the iPhone Forever Plan.

Recently, I had my iPhone Forever Plan phone stolen, and I'm not sure what to do.

1. AppleCare+ does not cover or help against theft.
2. AT&T insurance does not cover iPhone Forever Plan phones
3. My credit card does not cover phones that are paid over a payment plan spanning more than 90 days.
4. My renter's insurance also does not cover subscription payment items.
5. I actually have a few suspects, but the police does not seem to care enough to get warrants to search, claiming stolen phones are very low on their priority.

Is my only solution to pay back the iPhone at a loss, and start a new plan?

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Was find my iPhone turned on?   I actually wondered what happaned to a stolen iPhone forever when these plans were first coming out.

Comment: Phone either out of batteries or sim card popped

Comment: Neither would prevent 'Find my iPhone' alerting you next time the device ever sees any connection, on-air or wifi.